# How do I know if a C program will written on Linux will work elsewhere

Tags: c, linux, windows, operating-system

I need you to explain me how do I know if my C program will work for example on Windows if I write it on Linux and it works on that Linux and vice-versa (program written in Windows)

Also what standards do I have to follow to write programs that will run on different operating systems? How do I detect whether functions from libraries or whole libraries will work on different operating systems?

For example I have functions `fread`, `fwrite`, `fopen`, `fclose`from library `stdio.h` - how do I know if I can work with them properly on other systems than Linux? Same with functions that work with file descriptors: `open`, `creat`, `close`, `read`, `write` from libraries: `sys/types.h`, `sys/stat.h`, `fcntl.h`.

Comment: The hard way: by reading the documentation.  The easier way: compiling and testing it on Windows. Rule of thumb: `stdio.h` stuff is generally more or less compatible.

Comment: most of your standard libs work on both windows and linux

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run C program written in Linux on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474685/run-c-program-written-in-linux-on-windows)

Comment: By program, you mean the source code that is compiled for different platforms, or the binary compiled for a single platform?

Comment: If you're feeling particularly mischievous and _really_ like linux, you could make it as incompatible with any other OS as possible. Then, not only do you get to ignore compatibility problems, but you get a crowd of people using your favourite OS just to use your software. Win win! (This is a joke, don't actually do this)

Comment: What kind of programs do you want to write? For command line programs processing just files, it could be easy. For anything else, you'll better find a framework library which exists on both platforms (e.g. [GTK](http://gtk.org/), but I leave you to check that). Of course, you can only hope for *source* protability

Comment: @Eugen Sh. For sure I mean the first version

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, this is kind of simple: Your program will work on Windows as long as it only uses two things:

- The C standard library, as described in the C standard. See e.g. [n1570.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), the latest draft version that's very close to the *actual* standard. Note that a lot of C standard libraries come with all sorts of extensions, of course you can't use *these*. If in doubt, compile e.g. with the `-std=c11` option (`gcc` or `clang`) which should hide all declarations for extensions.

  There's an additional pitfall here: Microsoft's implementation of the C standard isn't complete. It depends on your compiler which C standard library is actually linked, in case of `MinGW`, it's the very old `msvcrt.dll` that only conforms to C89, so you *might* want to read an older standard instead for which functions you can use, e.g. [here's a description of the standard library in C89](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.) With Microsoft's C compilers, you get different levels of C99 support also in the standard libraries (they link their own runtime DLLs), depending on the version.
- Third party libraries that are available for Windows, like e.g. `SDL`, `GTK+`, etc.

By using `open`, `creat`, `close`, `read`, `write` etc., you're using extensions specified in POSIX. Some of the POSIX functions are available on Windows, some are slightly different, some are just missing. You better shouldn't use these if you want to stay portable to Windows. The exception to this rule is if you plan to compile your code with [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), which is a complete POSIX compatibility layer for Windows.

As per IanAbbott's comment, it's also crucial to use integer types *correctly* and not implicitly assume things like "*a `long` has 64 bits*" or "*an `int` can hold a pointer*", which are wrong in the general case. Always use the `<stdint.h>` types for fixed widths, `uintptr_t` for pointer values, `size_t` for object sizes, and so on.

---

Although not directly related to your question: For most non-trivial programs, you will sooner or later need to use some platform-specific functionality. Often, there are libraries abstracting this away, like e.g. if you need to handle I/O events efficiently, instead of using `epoll` on Linux, `kqueue` on FreeBSD, `IO completion ports` on Windows and so on, you could just use `libevent`. But in case you don't find such a library, here's a tip:

Clearly separate platform-specific code into its own modules (translation units). This way, the work for *porting* the whole thing to a different platform gets significantly smaller.

Comment: The programmer also needs to be aware of differences in the standard integer types between the two platforms (and between different Linux userland architectures). For example, `unsigned long` is 64 bits wide on 64-bit Linux, but 32 bits wide on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: @IanAbbott I assume reasonable usage of the types for what they're intended for, like use `(u)intN_t` for exact widths, `size_t` for sizes and so on. But of course, you have to consider this.

Comment: It's worth adding that the POSIX standard came about because the US Department of Defence wanted systems built and written around an open standard. They had got fed up of buying software that couldn't be ported to alternate platforms, and didn't like being held to ransom by defence suppliers. POSIX, for all it's foibles, has been pretty good at making things easier. It's an admirable thing for them to have done, and it's high time there were obligatory open standards for new things like clouds, OTT networks, etc.